# Evaluating a mathematical equation in an Array

Tags: java, android, token, equals

Im working on a simple app about factoring polynomials and so far i have used

```
.equals();
```

to check and compare the answers. But i realized that for example 4x^2 + 2x - 4 is the same as 2x + 4x^2 - 4. I am wondering how i can check without adding "2x + 4x^2 - 4" in my array? I thought about splitting it into tokens but how do i compare it tho?

Comment: i think you should first arrange the polynomial in descending order for that you have to check the power of variable look at here https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Answer (score 1):

split the array on based of operators, then you can compare each term separately. even order of terms can be checked. 
Since this is a string i see no other solution to this.